# CryptDeriveKey (OID) is unknown with SHA256 under Windows 7 64 bits

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, .net-3.5

I'm testing some components I built with VS2008 SP1 targeting .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.
I'm getting the exception "(OID) is unknown" in the method `PasswordDeriveBytes.CryptDeriveKey` passing "SHA256" as the parameter of the hashing algorithm (I also tried with "SHA256Managed" and "SHA256Cng" as mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnfa/archive/2007/01/17/new-crypto-algorithms-in-orcas.aspx)). This method works OK under XP SP3. As I understand these algorithms were added with the SP1 of 3.5 and Windows 7 comes with 3.5 SP1.

So my question is how I can get SHA256 under Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

to http://www.codeplex.com/clrsecurity/SourceControl/changeset/view/18423 and click "Download".
   b.      Unzip and build the downloaded Security.Cryptography\src\Security.Cryptography.csproj VS 2008 project.
   c.       Write a program to call Security.Cryptography.Oid2.RegisterSha2OidInformationForRsa().
   d.      Execute that program, which will register SHA-256 OID with the OS.
   e.      If this is a 64-bit architecture, you must also recompile the program for the x86 platform and execute it. This is because Visual Studio 2008 is a 32-bit application and requires that the same changes be made in the 32-bit registry.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RegisterSHA256
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("++++Begin to register SHA-256++++");
            Security.Cryptography.Oid2.RegisterSha2OidInformationForRsa();
            Console.WriteLine("++++ End to register SHA-256+++++");
        }
    }
}